# log4j is not working with Jetty and liftweb app

Tags: scala, log4j, jetty, lift

I'm using a liftweb service over Jetty with log4j for logging.

here is how I setup the logger in Boot class:

```
val config = Properties.envOrElse("log4j.configuration","/props/syslog.log4j.xml")
val configFile = getClass.getResource(config)
Logger.setup = Full(Log4j.withFile(configFile))
```

When running the app as service (**service jetty start**), I can't see any log files written.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my syslog.log4j.xml configuration file:

```
<root>
    <level value="trace"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CA"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CA2"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you confirm what the variable `config` is being set to? Also, have you verified that `configFile` has a URL that resolves to the log4j config file?

Comment: @jcern Actually, I have introduced those variables (for a sake of readability), not user49204. Before that code looked [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13919924/1).

Comment: Did you check that the jetty user has the proper file permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this wiki page to set up log4j:
https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Logging